# Why is the name "orthogonality"?

Tags: definition, abelian-groups, analytic-number-theory, orthogonality, dirichlet-character

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $\hat G$ be the character group of $G$.Let $G=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ and $\hat G=\{f_1,f_2,...,f_n\}$.$a_1$ is the identity of $G$ and $f_1$ is the principal character.Then we have the following relations:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n f_i(a_j)=\begin{cases}n &\text{if }j=1\\0&\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

and,

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n f_i(a_j)=\begin{cases}n &\text{if }i=1\\0&\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

I want to know why these are called "orthogonality" relation.I want to find suitable reason for nomenclature.

The definition of orthogonal which we know is something like $f_i(a_j)=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } i=j\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

But here it is not so.So can someone explain me the reason behind the name "orthogonality".

Comment: Your definition describes orthonormality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These relations say that the characters of $G$ are orthogonal for the inner product $\langle .,. \rangle$ defined on $\mathbb C^{G}$ (the space of all functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$, which has dimension $n$) by
$$\langle \varphi, \psi \rangle  = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{g \in G} \overline{\varphi(g)}\psi(g)$$

Comment: I edited the post as set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ is denoted by $Y^X$,

Comment: @KishalaySarkar Yes, typo.

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonality of the first relation can be extracted if we write $a_j$ as a product of two elements. That is

$$
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{f_i(a_u)}f_i(a_v)=
\begin{cases}
1 & u=v \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$